# React Native AsyncStorage Error when I want store data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, parsing

I'm doing an operation inside my function and I want to store my JSON data with AsyncStorage and use it elsewhere, but I'm getting an error in react native

this is my code block;

```
                  onPress={() => {
                    press = item.id;
                    // console.warn(press);

                    ars = options;
                    dd = JSON.stringify(ars);
                    cc = JSON.parse(dd);
                    for (var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
                      if (cc[i].id == press) {
                        // console.warn(cc[i]);
                        var productData = cc[i];

                        var stri = JSON.stringify(cc[i]);
                        AsyncStorage.setItem('ProductData', stri);
                        var abc = AsyncStorage.getItem('ProductData');
                        console.warn(stri);
                        console.warn(abc);
                      }
                    }
                  }}>
```

[image: console.warn(stri) output is ;]
[image: console.warn(abc output is ;)]

how can i solve that problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var abc = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ProductData');
```

add await as it is promise that all

so whole code will look like this

```
                  onPress={async () => {
                press = item.id;
                // console.warn(press);

                ars = options;
                dd = JSON.stringify(ars);
                cc = JSON.parse(dd);
                for (var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
                  if (cc[i].id == press) {
                    // console.warn(cc[i]);
                    var productData = cc[i];

                    var stri = JSON.stringify(cc[i]);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('ProductData', stri);
                    var abc =await AsyncStorage.getItem('ProductData');
                    console.warn(stri);
                    console.warn(abc);
                  }
                }
              }}>
```

add async to function and add await